# A CMS for multiple user login

Tags: django, drupal, content-management-system

I am trying to create a portal.

The portal should allow multiple user logins. The users are customers and upon login they should be able to check their sales, repository and stuff like that. Users won't need to be post blog, or anything like that, just simple checking of their daily sales.

As the admin, i, of course, should be able to edit all accounts.

I am contemplating to use a CMS such as Drupal, unless there is no such solutions, maybe a framework such as RoR would work too.

My question is, which open source CMS/framework should I use?

Comment: Whichever you are most comfortable working with

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you try Drupal because you can create your sales and repository info as "content". If it's suitable it would be much more productive and less error-prone than coding up something from scratch.

A common misconception of Drupal is that it is only suited for editorial written content like blog posts or articles. By using [CCK](http://drupal.org/project/cck) and [views](http://drupal.org/project/views) you can quickly set up some CRUD functionality and more.

Here's a nice intro to [CCK](http://media.gotdrupal.com/matt/acquia/d6/DrupalContentTypes_d6.mov).

Answer (score 0):

That sounds like pretty standard requirements for a extranet site, django or RoR seem a obvious choice. CMS's like Drupal, django-cms, Plone etc. are more concerned with content such as texts.

Choose your tool according to your current skills. I myself prefer django, but RoR will be better if you already know ruby.

Comment: Drupal has no problem dealing with structured content (not only text-based) and I bet most mature CMS does.

Answer (score 0):

CMS won't suit you because they are basically designed for managing content. Your requirements seem to far simple from that. If you are familiar with python, you can do such a site in 20 mins using Django.

I have no experience with Ruby of RoR!